# SonarQube and Jenkins, issue with integration

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I had integrated sonarqube with the jenkins  by adding a plugging and changing the configuration. But after i build a project, the build is succeded but not analysis results are added to  sonarqube UI. And I cannot click on SonarQube link in the project page after build. but if i run the sonarqube analysis without jenkins i get the results in the web UI.

[image]

the sonarqube was also injected to the build:
[according to the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpE5F.png).
Can you please help me to get my integration correct?
Best regads,
Nadis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install SonarQube Runner and configure it with Jenkins under [SonarQube Runner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner) section (Go to Manage Jenkins ->Configure System).

For step by step information on "Configuring Sonar with Jenkins" follow this [link](http://blogs.techcushions.com/2016/12/configuring-sonar-with-jenkins.html).